# Upload image from html input to S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to create a webpage where a person can upload an image and that image is stored in S3 bucket. Currently, I am getting this error: "Unsupported body payload object" while uploading to S3 bucket.

Here is my relevant HTML:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/editprofile" method="post">
   <input type="file" value="Change Profile Picture" name="profilePicture" id="profilePicture" >
</form>
```

Here is my relevant JS code:

```js
//in app.js
const fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileupload());
app.post('/editprofile', function(req, res) {
  routes.editprofile(req, res);
});

//in routes.js in editprofile function
db.putInBucket("bucket", "key" + ".png", req.files.profilePicture);

//in db in putInBucket
var putInBucket = function (bucket, key, file) {
  var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
      Body: file
    }
  });

  var promise = upload.promise();
  promise.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error in uploading to S3" + error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert content of `req.files.profilePicture` into binary before uploading to `S3`.

```
var binaryProfilePicture = new Buffer(req.files.profilePicture, "binary");

db.putInBucket("bucket", "key" + ".png", binaryProfilePicture );
```